# How do I pass multiple parameters into an sql statement in python?

Tags: python, sql, parameters

I've tried many different ways and researched but can't find a simple way of passing multiple parameters to an sql statement like this:

```
age=clicked1.get()
#e.g (u15)
gender=clicked2.get()
#e.g (Men)

        c.execute("""SELECT USR_name, USR_surname FROM User_TBL
                            WHERE User_ID=(SELECT User_ID FROM Players_To_Teams
                            WHERE Team_ID=(SELECT Team_ID FROM Teams_TBL WHERE Team_Age=?, AND 
                            Team_Gender=?))""", [age,gender])
        players = c.fetchall()
```

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? Seems the most obvious way. And assuming you use this connector, the question marks should be `%s`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-select.html

Comment: You can always try f-string replacements instead `f"""SELECT USR_name, USR_surname FROM User_TBL
                            WHERE User_ID=(SELECT User_ID FROM Players_To_Teams
                            WHERE Team_ID=(SELECT Team_ID FROM Teams_TBL WHERE Team_Age={age}, AND 
                            Team_Gender={gender}))"""`

Comment: @fam-woodpecker that is a terrible idea, you are opening up your system to sql injection attacks. Building your query with f-strings only can be done if you have 100% certainty that your input data do not come from a user in any way.